# how to sum two columns and insert into total column automatically after every update

Tags: mysql

I have three columns column 1, column 2, column 3(total). i want to put the sum of column 1 and column 2 into column 3 after every update query..... note i am using code igniter.. how can i do it if i update col 1 then total column automatically update itself.

Comment: you can use triggers to achieve this.

Comment: how to use trigger?

Comment: You can easily do this with slight modification to your update command. UPDATE table1 SET COL1=X, COL3=X+COL2 WHERE ........  . X is your input value. When ever you update COL1 the same query updates COL3 as well.

Comment: @MuhammadAhsanAyazKhan check my answer.

Comment: @dsharew update total col with update query looks smart.. what you suggest..

Comment: yeah but always be cautious to update col3 when col1 or col2 changes on the other hand using triggers is automatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER updtrigger AFTER UPDATE ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.col1 <> OLD.col1 OR NEW.col2 <> OLD.col2 THEN
        SET NEW.col3 = NEW.col1 + New.col2;     
    END IF;
END $$
```

Here is a very good [tutorial](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_update.php).

> An AFTER UPDATE Trigger means that MySQL will fire this trigger after
>   the UPDATE operation is executed.

Comment: you wrote BEFORE AFTER , will it execute before and after query??? plus you wrote FOR EACH ROW but i want to execute it for that row only of which column is being updated.. kindly edit to what i require... thanks

Comment: yeah sorry I removed the BEFORE; you need the FOR EACH ROW because you could update multiple rows on a single query.

Comment: ok thanks now last thing where my query will take place in this trigger code

Comment: you have to run the query when you create the table or run it directly on your database console or write a migration script if you are using any migration plugin. Once you run this query it will work for all the time.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you just update the db instead of creating a trigger. plus youve created the trigger after the insert, it should go before. but really you shouldn't be doing it that way

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `db_name`.`trigger_name` AFTER UPDATE
    ON `db_name`.`table_name`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE
        `table_name`
    SET
        `column3` = `column1` + `column2`;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```